# IDE's help files are not up to date?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I'm trying to enable Code Insight. I clicked on Help.  Under the topic "Code Insight Options", at the top, it says to enable Code Insight "Tools > Options > User Interface > Editor Options > Source and click on Code Insight option."   My 10.4 version doesn't have "Editor Options" and nothing nearby has "Code Insight" as an option.

It would be nice if the help files that come with a build correlated to the build, no?  Does anyone know how to turn on Code Insight?

This is on "Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.4 Version 27.0.40680.4203"

Comment: In my 10.4 CE version I have Code Insight options under: Options - User Interface - Editor - Language - Code Insight. Code Insight is an item in the horizontal menu beneath the Language selection box. However, the Code Insight Manager drop down seems disabled.

Comment: Well, that led to something.  I actually set the language to C++, which wasn't set before.  (I'd have thought it would do that automatically upon changing source code language, via the file extension, but maybe you have to go that deep into options to find it?)  But... no help.